# Advanced: understanding wp_add_inline_style function

Tags: css

I really read a lot of articles relating adding dynamic inline stylesheet. but this one drives me crazy. i have a simple dev setup. 
this is my global style:

```
function bootstrap_scripts_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css', array(), '2016-07-18' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap_scripts_styles' );
```

because i need to trigger custom styles from single.php, i added some sample code here:

```
$custom_css = ".intro { background: red; }";
wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $custom_css );
```

using this, nothing happens. i don't see any inline style in frontend code. But when i debug WP_Styles() and look for "custom-style" i can see, the style is being appended:

```
[custom-style] => _WP_Dependency Object
                (
                    [handle] => custom-style
                    [src] => http://localhost/westerland/wp-content/themes/westerland/style.css
                    [deps] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [ver] => 2013-07-18
                    [args] => all
                    [extra] => Array
                        (
                            [after] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => .intro { background: red; }
                                )

                        )

                )
```

so i wonder why it does not get printed?! i found a way to print it, but then, it gets printed in `<body>` instead right behind the `<link>` tag of global style:

```
$custom_css = ".intro { background: red; }";
wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $custom_css );
WP_Styles()->print_inline_style("custom-style");
```

so this feels a little bit "hacky" because i want this as clean as possible to appear in the `<head>` tag. is this some kind of bug? i am using latest WP.

Comment: Where do you call `wp_add_inline_style`;

Comment: as i wrote in single.php :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the following works for you. Just adapt the is_single() to is_singular('custom-post-type') if you want this on a single custom post type template specifically. Hope this helps.

```
function bootstrap_scripts_styles() {
  wp_enqueue_style('custom-style',get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap.css');
  $custom_css = ".intro { background: red; }";
  wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $custom_css );
}


function enqueue_inline_style( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_single()) {
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap_scripts_styles' );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'enqueue_inline_style' );
```

edit: obviously just enqueue the main stylesheet separately.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Svartbaart. Your answer lead me to the right direction. So the main problem with my approach was that i ran it in the single.php where it won't execute the print of the inline style. so what i did is to insert it in functions.php in its own function which gets triggered by wp_enqueue_scripts hook. the final code is this:

```
function inline_style() {
    global $post;
    if(is_single()) {
            $custom_css = ".intro { background:red }";
            wp_add_inline_style('custom-style', $custom_css);
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'inline_style' );
```

Comment: Or in `wp_head` :)